# Pyspark java heap out of memory when saving 5m rows dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a kaggle [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sobhanmoosavi/us-accidents) that I want to stream one record at a time based on the `Start_Time` column and the `End_Time` column.

I created a temporary table with both columns unioned, convert them to UNIX, and scale them to fit in the `RUNTIME` constant. I called this column `Stream_Time` . This means that every ID appears twice; once for start and once for end.

I then join the temporary table and the main dataframe on the ID column so that when I iterate through the `Stream_Time` column I can send all the data, instead of doing a subquery for the ID from the main dataframe.

The code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
RUNTIME = 600 #Constant

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, split, broadcast
from datetime import datetime


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .appName("USA Accidents Analysis with Pyspark") \
    .getOrCreate()

def toUnix(date):
    # This is to account for milliseconds, we don't care about such precision
    date = date.split('.')[0]
    date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return datetime.timestamp(date)

udfToUnix = udf(toUnix)

main_df = spark.read.csv('./US_Accidents_Dec21_updated.csv', header = True)

main_df = main_df.withColumn('Start_Time_Unix', udfToUnix(main_df['Start_Time']) \
                                             .cast(FloatType()))
main_df = main_df.withColumn('End_Time_Unix', udfToUnix(main_df['End_Time'])
                                            .cast(FloatType()))

# Clean the ID column
main_df = main_df.withColumn('ID', split(main_df['ID'],'-').getItem(1).cast(IntegerType()))

temp_df = main_df.select('ID','Start_Time_Unix') \
        .union(main_df.select('ID','End_Time_Unix')) \
        .orderBy('Start_Time_Unix') \
        .orderBy('ID')

temp_df = temp_df.withColumn('Time_Unix',temp_df['Start_Time_Unix'])
earliest = temp_df.agg({'Time_Unix':"min"}).collect()
earliest = earliest[0][0]

latest = temp_df.agg({"Time_Unix":"max"}).collect()
latest = latest[0][0]

def scale(unix):
    return ((unix - earliest) / (latest - earliest)) * RUNTIME 

udfScaling = udf(scale,FloatType())
temp_df = temp_df.withColumn('Stream_Time',udfScaling(temp_df['Time_Unix']))

temp_df = temp_df.withColumnRenamed('ID','temp_id')
to_delete = ('Start_Time_Unix','End_Time_Unix','Time_Unix',"temp_id")

stream_df = temp_df.join(broadcast(main_df), temp_df.temp_id == main_df.ID) \
            .drop(*to_delete).orderBy('Stream_Time')

stream_df.write.parquet('./Stream3.parquet')
```

It all goes well till the last line, it generates this huge error

```
22/07/25 17:15:24 WARN package: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields'.
[Stage 10:>                                                       (0 + 12) / 12]
[54.853s][warning][gc,alloc] Executor task launch worker for task 2.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 78): Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 13796354 words
22/07/25 17:15:27 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 78)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3537)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:100)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:130)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.flushBufferedData(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:225)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.write(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.writeToStream(UnsafeRow.java:542)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$2634/0x0000000801956820.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$Lambda$2631/0x0000000801947ba0.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$2593/0x0000000801931968.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
22/07/25 17:15:28 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 2.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 78),5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3537)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:100)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:130)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.flushBufferedData(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:225)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.write(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.writeToStream(UnsafeRow.java:542)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$2634/0x0000000801956820.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$Lambda$2631/0x0000000801947ba0.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$2593/0x0000000801931968.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
22/07/25 17:15:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 78) (Fedora executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3537)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:100)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:130)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.flushBufferedData(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:225)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.write(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.writeToStream(UnsafeRow.java:542)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$2634/0x0000000801956820.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$Lambda$2631/0x0000000801947ba0.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$2593/0x0000000801931968.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

22/07/25 17:15:28 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 2 in stage 10.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
22/07/25 17:15:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 81) (Fedora executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
22/07/25 17:15:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 80) (Fedora executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
22/07/25 17:15:28 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job ba6edbb7-65d8-4c72-ae0a-ce4d4eb21b06.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 10.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 78) (Fedora executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3537)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:100)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:130)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.flushBufferedData(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:225)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.write(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.writeToStream(UnsafeRow.java:542)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$2634/0x0000000801956820.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$Lambda$2631/0x0000000801947ba0.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$2593/0x0000000801931968.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2249)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2268)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2293)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1021)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1020)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectIterator(SparkPlan.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.$anonfun$relationFuture$1(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1(SQLExecution.scala:191)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3537)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:100)
    at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:130)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.flushBufferedData(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:225)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.write(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.writeToStream(UnsafeRow.java:542)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$Lambda$2634/0x0000000801956820.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$Lambda$2631/0x0000000801947ba0.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$2593/0x0000000801931968.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    ... 3 more
22/07/25 17:15:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 84) (Fedora executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
22/07/25 17:15:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 87) (Fedora executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
22/07/25 17:15:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 83) (Fedora executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
22/07/25 17:15:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 10.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 86) (Fedora executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
22/07/25 17:15:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 79) (Fedora executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
22/07/25 17:15:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 77) (Fedora executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
22/07/25 17:15:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 9.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 85) (Fedora executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
22/07/25 17:15:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 82) (Fedora executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
22/07/25 17:15:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 76) (Fedora executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 47890)
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: <unprintable Py4JJavaError object>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/clientserver.py", line 516, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1038, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/clientserver.py", line 539, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while sending or receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 281, in handle
    poll(accum_updates)
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 253, in poll
    if func():
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 257, in accum_updates
    num_updates = read_int(self.rfile)
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py", line 595, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
----------------------------------------
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/clientserver.py", line 516, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1038, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/clientserver.py", line 539, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while sending or receiving
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py:190, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    189 try:
--> 190     return f(*a, **kw)
    191 except Py4JJavaError as e:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:

<class 'str'>: (<class 'ConnectionRefusedError'>, ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 66>()
     61 stream_df = temp_df.join(broadcast(main_df), temp_df.temp_id == main_df.ID) \
     62             .drop(*to_delete).orderBy('Stream_Time')
     64 stream_df.printSchema()
---> 66 stream_df.write.parquet('./Stream3.parquet')

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:1140, in DataFrameWriter.parquet(self, path, mode, partitionBy, compression)
   1138     self.partitionBy(partitionBy)
   1139 self._set_opts(compression=compression)
-> 1140 self._jwrite.parquet(path)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py:192, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    190     return f(*a, **kw)
    191 except Py4JJavaError as e:
--> 192     converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
    193     if not isinstance(converted, UnknownException):
    194         # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    195         # JVM exception message.
    196         raise converted from None

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py:170, in convert_exception(e)
    167 c: Py4JJavaError = e.getCause()
    168 stacktrace: str = jvm.org.apache.spark.util.Utils.exceptionString(e)
    169 if c is not None and (
--> 170     is_instance_of(gw, c, "org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException")
    171     # To make sure this only catches Python UDFs.
    172     and any(
    173         map(
    174             lambda v: "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python" in v.toString(), c.getStackTrace()
    175         )
    176     )
    177 ):
    178     msg = (
    179         "\n  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. "
    180         "Please see the stack trace below.\n%s" % c.getMessage()
    181     )
    182     return PythonException(msg, stacktrace)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:464, in is_instance_of(gateway, java_object, java_class)
    460 else:
    461     raise Py4JError(
    462         "java_class must be a string, a JavaClass, or a JavaObject")
--> 464 return gateway.jvm.py4j.reflection.TypeUtil.isInstanceOf(
    465     param, java_object)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1722, in JVMView.__getattr__(self, name)
   1719 _, error_message = get_error_message(answer)
   1720 message = compute_exception_message(
   1721     "{0} does not exist in the JVM".format(name), error_message)
-> 1722 raise Py4JError(message)

Py4JError: py4j does not exist in the JVM

ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/clientserver.py", line 516, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1038, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/clientserver.py", line 539, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while sending or receiving
```

I didn't install spark from apache, I just used `pip install pyspark`.
I tried alot of solutions here on SO, including repartitioning, coalesce, setting `.config('spark.driver.memory','10g')` in the SparkSession doesn't work, and setting values higher than 10g forcibly closes jupyter/terminal.

It doesn't need to be in parquet, I just need to save it so that I can read it from another script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You post covers several questions and optimization:

1. `It all goes well till the last line, it generates this huge error`: The reason why you only get error message when you execute the last line of code is because the spark computation mechanism. All RDD in spark support two operations: `transformations`, which create a new dataset from an existing one, and `actions`, which return a value to the driver program after running a computation on the dataset. All `transformations` in Spark are **lazy** and only be executed when action is required. You can check RDD operation for more detail:
   https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations. Based on the code that you provided, the only `action` that in your code is the `collect` and `write.parquet(...)`. Therefore, it is possible that the error code occurs when last line of code is executed. In fact, it doesn't mean that the `write.parquet(...)` operation cause the OOM in Java heap space, you have to check the spark log to see which transformation cause this error.
2. Based on the code you provided, you use user-defined functions to do the transformation that can be done by the built-in functions. Remember to use the Spark built-in functions as much as possible, only use the user-defined functions (UDF) when your transformation cant't be done with the built-in functions. It's because the logic in UDF can't be optimized by Spark Catalyst optimizer. Also since you're using pyspark, you write your UDF by Python and it will move the data back and forth between Python and Java. These two post show a good discussion on why you should use built-in functions rather than UDF:
   [When is it appropriate to use a UDF vs using spark functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65907514/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-a-udf-vs-using-spark-functionality) and [Spark functions vs UDF performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance)
3. `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` doesn't mean that there is not enough memory for the driver, lack of resources in executors will cause this error too. Please check if your executor resource is enough or not and also the number of partitions that you use. Also, noticed that you're loading the data frame by `csv` but not `parquet`, please check the number of record in each partition by `df.groupBy(func.spark_partition_id()).count()` to see if there is too much of data in a single partition? These two post show a good discussion on consider the partitioning and OOM debugging issue: [Spark java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : Java Heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082110/spark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space) and [Spark java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138751/spark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)

Comment: 1. I know the difference between actions, transformations, and lazy computation. However, running some actions like `count()` doesn't cause the error; only the `write` does.

2. I didn't assume spark had a `unix_timestamp` so I didn't bother googling it. I removed both UDFs and the script is much much faster now.

3. I followed some of the advice from the first link (the second is mostly about clusters, not single nodes) namely reducing cores and increasing partitions (initial partitions were unbalanced like you suggested) and now both `write` and `coalesce(1).write` work well.

Comment: Is there a book/course that talks about such internals for spark?

Comment: 1. It depends on what kind of action are you requiring, for example `.take(1)` is one of the cheapest action, `.count()` just provide a counting number back to driver, `.collect()` is much expensive than `.take(1)`. It's really depends on your transformations and actions. 2. Unfortunately I don't have any good book or course that I can recommend to you, but I think most of OOM errors are either related to insufficient resource, misunderstanding of Spark memory management or data skew. Unless you're doing some sophisticated job like sparse matrix calculation, you can start with above 3 angles.